# Remark about direct product of groups

Tags: group-theory

This is an excerpt from Herstein's book and I would like to understand the meaning of text which I've marked with red line.

[image]

The author says that the theorem proves the following thing: If $G\cong G_1\times G_2\times \dots \times G_n$ then $G=\bar{G_1}\bar{G_2}\dots \bar{G}_n$, where $\bar{G}_i\cong G_i$.

However, after detailed reading the statement and proof of theorem I've realized that theorem and paragraph (marked with red) are somewhat converse facts. Maybe I am wrong.

Notation: By $\bar{G}_i$ Herstein means the following $\{(e_1,\dots,e_{i-1}, g_i, e_{i+1},\dots, e_n): g_i\in G_i\}$ where $e_i$ - the unit in group $G_i$.

Can anyone explain in detail why the theorem proves the red paragraph?

Comment: Well, a more direct way of stating what that paragraph say is: an external direct product of groups is the internal product of subgroup isomorphic to to the factors..

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, I guess that paragraph means the following: $G_1\times G_2\times \dots \times G_n \cong \bar{G}_1\bar{G}_2\dots \bar{G}_n$ where $\bar{G}_i\cong G_i$.

Comment: Exactly (and where on the right the product is direct)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, Does it follow from theorem? If yes, could you explain it, please?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, Maybe i am misunderstanding something :/

Comment: Imho you are right. I can see how both statements are true but not how the red one can be derived from the theorem. It is the converse indeed.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Yes, indeed. I am not able to prove the statement (in red paragraph). It would be great if anyone can show how to do it.

Comment: First show that an external product is isomorphic to the internal product of the obvious subgroups. 
Then if a group is isomorphic to an external product, pullback the above structure via the isomorphism.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, 1) The external product $G_1\times G_2\times \dots \times G_n$ is isomorphic to $\bar{G}_1\bar{G}_2\dots \bar{G}_n$ since the mapping $\phi: G_1\times G_2\times \dots \times G_n \to \bar{G}_1\bar{G}_2\dots \bar{G}_n$ defined by $\phi(g_1, g_2,\dots, g_n)=(g_1, g_2,\dots, g_n)$ is bijective homomorphism. What is next? What do you mean by "pullback"?

Comment: Then if $\Gamma\simeq G_1\times\ldots\times G_n$, consider the subgroups of $\Gamma$ given by $\phi^{-1}(\bar{G_i})$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, $\Gamma\cong G_1\times \dots \times G_n$ and $G_1\times \dots \times G_n\cong \bar{G}_1\dots \bar{G}_n$. You said that I need to consider subgroups $\phi^{-1}(\bar{G}_i)$ in $\Gamma$, but $\phi^{-1}(\bar{G}_i)$ lies in $G_1\times \dots G_n$. Maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: The $\phi$ in this context goes from $\Gamma$ to the external product. I just skipped the isomorphism between the external and internal product that you have on the right.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I didn't understand you. The mapping $\phi$ is from $G_1\times \dots \times G_n$ to $\bar{G}_1\dots \bar{G}_n$. Could you explain your reasoning in more detailed. It's quite complicated for me to follow you

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that you had used the notation $\phi$ before. Let me reformulate: if $\Gamma\simeq G_1\times\ldots\times G_n$ via an isomorphism $\Psi$, then consider the subgroups $\Psi^{-1}\circ\phi^{-1}(\bar{G_i})$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Let's consider $\phi^{-1}(\bar{G}_1)$. It is easy to found that $\phi^{-1}(\bar{G}_1)=\{(g_1,e_2,\dots, e_n): g_1\in G_1\}=G_1\times \{e_2\}\times \dots \times \{e_n\}$. Then $\Psi^{-1}\circ \phi^{-1}(\bar{G}_1)=\Psi^{-1}(G_1\times \{e_2\}\times \dots \times \{e_n\})$. I don't know what to do next since I don't know how mapping $\Psi$ acts.

Comment: Simply prove that the pulled back subgroups still satisfy the relevant axioms (their intersection is the identity, their product generates the whole group, any two elements from one and another commute). This is all true because an isomorphism preserves these properties.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, i dont understand the meaning of pulled back subgroup. Could you give a detailed proof in separate answer? We have too many comments. Would be very grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a chain of isomorphisms $$\Gamma\stackrel{\Psi}{\to} G_1×⋯×G_n\stackrel{\phi}{\to} \bar{G_1}\ldots \bar{G_n}$$

Now set $$\Gamma_i=\Psi^{-1}\left(\phi^{-1}(\bar{G_i})\right)$$

Simply because the two maps are isomorphisms give you everything you need:

- The $\Gamma_i$ are normal subgroups of $\Gamma$
- $h_i\in \Gamma_i$ and $h_j\in \Gamma_j$ will commute as soon as $i\neq j$
- $\Gamma_i\ \cap \left<\bigcup_{j\neq i} \Gamma_j\right>=\left\lbrace e\right\rbrace $

All of these properties are structural (preserved via isomorphisms).

Therefore $\Gamma\cong \Gamma_1 \ldots\Gamma_n$ where $\Gamma_i\cong G_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: But the book states that $\Gamma=\bar{G}_1\bar{G}_2 \dots \bar{G}_n$. However you have not this in your answer.

Comment: Dear Arnauld, I've aksed the question. Could you answer it, please?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was away. If you look carefully the red paragraph indicates "*isomorphic* to an internal product of subgroups that are *isomorphic* to the $\bar{G_i}$". Not "=", just "isomorphic".